# Scrolling text became a real pain..?

Tags: c#, drawing, scroll

Hi I am working on c# 2005 with a scrolling application.At first I use some of these

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csmarquee.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ScrollingTextControlArtic.aspx

but all of them cannot help me much.My application contains 7timers.At the time of running it 
the scrolling panel looks so irritating(read not at all smooth).
 so I finally tried with a simple panel ,a label and a timer,this also not working (i mean not smooth).

Can there be any other way rather then using timer,to scroll a text.

Comment: The classic problem is using a fast timer and only scrolling by one pixel.  That produces an artifact called 'tearing', looks like flickering pixels.  Can't fix that without hardware assistance, updating only during the vertical blanking interval.  Slow down the timer, scroll by more than one pixel.

Comment: 7 timers is pretty unusual. Can't think of ever having more than two or so on one form.

Comment: @  Hans Passant thnx for sharing this information.:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what is wrong with your scrolling without any code but you will get much smotther scrolling by using Double Buffering. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered

But there is limitation how much "animation" you can do with windows forms and have it smooth. Using DirectX or Silverlight will be better for graphics.

Comment: thnx for the answer.ur link was a real deal.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer to control the rate of scroll should be OK. It sounds like you might not be double buffering your controls which is the usual cause of jerky animation. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20121123031717/http://www.bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.htm), among many, on using double buffering for controls.

But first just try and set the [DoubleBuffered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered) property to true on your form. That setting alone may fix your animation.

Comment: thnx for providing the "DoubleBuffered" concept.let's see if I can do any progress with it.